# How to prevent right-to-left text appearance while using Arabic language?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to construct a string which contains arabic symbols and stringified formated numbers. It looks like:

```
var str = "some_arabic_text: " + "10 834,26" + " more_arabic_text: " + "2 921,96"
myDiv.innerHTML = str;
```

But this string appears in reversed order in myDiv. The numbers are also uglified to "438,62 01" or something like that. I don't need this in my case. How to prevent reversing?

Important to say, that this CSS rule doesn't help:

```
#myDiv {direction: ltr;}
```

**EDIT:**

I also noticed that if I use `console.log(str)` it already appears in reversed order in browser's console. The string becomes wrong even before using `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found. `<bdo>` tag can override this behavior.

```
var str = "<bdo>" + "some_arabic_text: " + "10 834,26" + " more_arabic_text: " + "2 921,96" + "</bdo>"
```